# not able to install an ipa file with Chinese name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipa

I have application built in Chinese name. I archived it for ad-hoc distribution. the IPA file's file name is of Chinese characters. Installing this ipa file via iphone configuration utility fails.

Kindly help. My requirement is to have ipa file with Chinese name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why have not used the iTunes to install the app instead? all UDIDs have been added to the distribution profile?

Comment: From iTunes it is getting installed properly. Only problem is with IPCU. I dont understand why? all the distribution profiles are in place

Comment: is there any particular reason why you need to use the IPCU against the iTunes?

Comment: Customer wanted to get it installed via IPCU also

Answer (score -1):

use http://diawi.com/

Upload your IPA file there and they send link to your devices, and you can install by clicking on the link. No registration required..